# mysql select not repeated random numbers from database

Tags: mysql, select, random

I just wonder whether I can make it or not.
Thank you for helping me in advance.

I have 100000 ids in my database.
I want to select random 10 ids out of 100000.
If I go to the next page, I also select random 10 ids(which are not repeated with previous ids) from database
Finally I select all 100000 ids.

If I refresh my page, it restarts from the beginning.

I have an idea that select random numbers with seed 1000 times and store it on redis and pop out every 10 rows when a user enter the page . Are there any different ideas?

I need 10 random ids at time. I need to get a new set of random ids every time I ask for a new set, but but the new ones must not include any of the ones I already got from any number of previous times I asked for a new set Unless the process is reset. I may have a total of 100 or 1million ids in my database. I plan to use the ids to show 10 item at a on a webpage, with next and previous buttons. The pages already shown have to be consistent with the original items shown if the users goes back to any previously shown page

From @ Scratte
Thanks for clarifying what I wanted to say!

If it's not possible, it is also fine. Thank you.

Comment: what's wrong with something like `SELECT xx FROM posts ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?*10, 10`?  i.e. this will work fine with large tables.  what performance characteristics do you care about?

Comment: @SamMason I have to get it from the database every time I push the next page button. If I go to the next page, then I might get same numbers with the previous page. Am I wrong?

For example,
First : 10,20,30,40,50,60,70
Second : 10,23,35,49,95,63,7,8,9,10 ( Duplicated)
... ( Total numbers should be 1 to 100)

Comment: would you please see my answer? @SamMason i think you can use js to solve this problem, not only MySQL.

Comment: @SamMason If you might feel bad on my comment, there is no offense in my comment. I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: The question needs details on what makes you unsure whether it is possible. Did you read anywhere that it is impossible? Did you try and fail? How exactly did you try and how did it fail? You explicitly state that you only want to know whether it is possible. But frankly I doubt that. If anybody answers "Yes." you will not be satisfied. A good answer hence would provide a demonstration, that however would be inappropriate for an question which basically says "I want." without any demonstration of research or effort.

Comment: Thank you guys for saying my mistakes. I will think more in deep.

Comment: Nice idea to put my answer type in the question and ask if there is a better way.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? You need 10 random ids at time. You need to get a new set of random ids every time you ask for a new set, but but the new ones must not include any of the ones you already got from any number of previous times you asked for a new set  Unless the process is reset? You may have a total of 100 or 1million ids in your database.  You plan to use the ids to show 10 item at a on a webpage, with next and previous buttons. The pages already shown have to be consistent with the original items shown if the users goes back to any previously shown page?

Answer (score 1):

I am just adding an idea here. You will need to convert it into code.

---

You first get rows from database in bulk, not in slices of `10`. This is to improve performance by reducing DB round trips.

Get 1000 rows from DB and store them in `session`.

**Query:**

```
Select *
from table
where id NOT IN (previous_ids)
order by rand()
limit 0,1000
```

**Note:** Since ID is an indexed column, `NOT IN` should be quicker.

Now, that you have 1000 rows, store all of them in session. When user requests a page that is a multiple of 1000, *only then* you fire another query to the DB. This gives you amortized performance. See below:

```
page_request = 1
if (page_request - 1) % 1000 == 0:
   fire DB to get next 1000 rows
   $_SESSION['data'][intval(page_request / 1000)] = fetched_rows
```

When user requests the page, you get the data as follows:

```
key = intval(page_request / 1000)
record_offset = (page_request % 1000 - 1) * 10
return array_splice($_SESSION['data'][key],record_offset,10)
```

If the user refreshes the page completely, you can just do a [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to reorder the elements randomly like `shuffle($_SESSION['data'][key])` and then return to the frontend.